# Schengen visa while waiting for residence permit renewal

Tags: schengen, italy, netherlands

I am a Turkish citizen, I am currently studying in Italy. 
My permit of residence has expired lately and in my city, it takes around 7-8 months to renew it.
However, I need to travel to the Netherlands for research purposes soon. So, do you know if it is possible to acquire a Dutch Schengen visa in this situation, if I go to the Dutch embassy directly?

Thanks